# Android Bitmap Scaling Incorrectly

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

I have a background resource with the dimensions of 854 x 480 (The exact screen resolution of my test phone).  When I load this resource into my app, it is scaled out of proportion.  I have searched through here and tried some of the suggestions, but for some crazy reason, it will not scale to the appropriate size.

Being that the resource is the same size as the screen, I'm not sure why it is increasing the size of the background resource.  It scales it up to 1281 x 720 and I do not know why.

The code where the conversion happens is:

```
public Sprite newSpriteLargeResource(Resources res, SpriteFormat format,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    Options options = new Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    options.inSampleSize = calculateSample(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    boolean scaled;
    scaled = m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    if (scaled) {
        float[] bmpValues = new float[9];
        m.getValues(bmpValues);
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                (int) ((bitmap.getWidth() * bmpValues[0])),
                (int) ((bitmap.getHeight() * bmpValues[4])), true);
    }else{
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, true);
    }


    return new AndroidSprite(bitmap, format);
}

private int calculateSample(Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {


        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);


        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;

}
```

You may notice multiple versions of the scaling.  The only reason I kept the code like this is to show that I have tried multiple versions of the scaling and all of them have not worked like I had hoped.  I know the problem lies somewhere in these two methods as I have another method for non-background resources and they work fine.  The only reason I am using this one is for larger image files to avoid having an Out of Memory exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What drawable folder is your resource in?   Sound like you're putting your image resource in a density bucket that's too low.  Because your wrong dimensions are exactly 1.5x your desired dimensions.

For example, if you only put your 854 x 480 image resource in drawable-hdpi, it will render it on an xhdpi device at 1281 x 720.  i.e. Android will scale your image up 1.5s. That's the correct behavior.  You're telling Android that your image is to be drawn 480px wide on an hdpi device.  But now you're viewing a denser screen, more pixels to draw the same image, so it should be drawn at 720px width on a device that's 1.5x denser.

If you put your image in a higher density bucket, you should have the right behavior.

The proper way to do this is to provide an image for each bucket.

In general, it's good to understand how Android displays for different density displays, through different drawable-*dpi buckets, and also the concept of "dips" or Density Independent Pixels.

See these [docs on supporting different screens.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: nice.  I put it into drawable-nodpi and it works as expected.  Thanks again!